# I'm trying to display the percentage of red color in my image with OpenCV and Python

Tags: python, opencv, colors, hsv, bgr

I'm fairly new to both OpenCV and Python and I'm trying to calculate the number of red pixels and display it as a percent. However, it keeps displaying 0% even though there is a lot of red in the picture. Could someone please help me out?

This is what I have so far,

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('roi.jpg')
size = img.size


RED_MIN = np.array([0,0,128], np.uint8)
RED_MAX = np.array([250, 250, 255], np.uint8)


dstr = cv2.inRange(img, RED_MIN, RED_MAX)
no_red = cv2.countNonZero(dstr)
frac_red = np.divide((int(no_red)),(int(size)))
percent_red = np.multiply((int(frac_red)), 100)
print('Red: ' + str(percent_red) + '%')
```

Answer (score 2):

The bug seems to be in `frac_red = np.divide((int(no_red)),(int(size)))`, As you are explicitly converting both the operands to `int` before passing them to `np.divide()`, which would also return an `int` if both the operands are `int`, To get the precise decimal percentage, you need to pass either one or both of them as `float`:

```
frac_red = np.divide(float(no_red), int(size))
```

---

```
# Your current Scenario
In [5]: np.divide(3, 8)
Out[5]: 0

# Expected Scenario
In [7]: np.divide(3.0, 8)
Out[7]: 0.375
```